# C# system.stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I'm getting the below error message and not sure how to tackle it.

I have a loop that populates about 40 table rows on a webpage which has been working fine.

I've had one button on the table without any problems but if I add another 2 buttons then the error is occurring. The page loads and renders fine, and I can click the buttons without an issue.
But about ten seconds after the page loads I get the error and the debugger stops.

[image]

The additional code is basically two of these, a literal control that renders a couple of buttons with client-side click events onto a tablecell which is added to a tablerow which is added to the table.

```
tc = new TableCell();
lit1 = new Literal();
lit1.Text = "<i class='qtip tip-top' data-tip='Edit' onclick='fnLoadEditTemplate(" + et.EmailTemplateID + ");'><i class='templatesOptionsIcon fas fa-edit'></i>";
tc.Controls.Add(lit1);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```

I know I haven't provided much code, but I'm a little lost.

Where can I start in terms of tracking down this error?

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting tips in the message and ensure that you do not have an infinite loop or recursion? Stackoverflow often happens in one of these situations. The code you've shown wouldn't throw it on it's own, but if it were in an infinite loop, at some point you'd run out of memory to create a `new TableCell()` or a `new Literal()`

Comment: Hey Rufus, yes I'm aware that an infinite loop would result in this, but all I'm doing is adding another couple of steps to a loop.

The loop ends, the page loads, everything seems fine, no apparent locking up or slow downs. 10 seconds later, bamn error.

Comment: You might take a look at the [memory usage diagnostic tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio to help track down the problem.

Comment: "_all I'm doing is adding another couple of steps to a loop_" - famous last words ;)

Comment: Have a look at the call stack when the exception occurs.

Comment: I love `StackOverflow` questions on StackOverflow! Can you include the full code of the loop?

Comment: I would look to where  you call the added code. Could it be called by an event that would trigger the infinite loop e.g. a table update event?